# Color clicker in python

Tags: python, colors

I'm new to python so I'm trying to make a python bot for a simple game. I tried making a function that clicks on any color I want to, but I keep getting errors saying "The Pillow Package is required to use this function" does anyone know why? Here is the function.

```
def findColor():
    for x in range(s.width):
        for y in range(s.height):
            if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
                click(x, y)
```

And I made a function called click that will click in the place I want so that isn't the bug, color is a variable I made so I can change it if I need to, and s is a screenshot. The variable for s is

```
s = pyautogui.screenshot()
```

Also I am very new to python so if I did something really dumb please go easy on me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring since the screenshot function uses the PIL module,

This may help: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

according to the documentation,

"*Screenshot functionality requires the Pillow module.* "

*since `s` uses the screenshot module and returns a Image object, therefore PIL needs to be installed.*

Comment: Ok but how and where do I download it?

Comment: @ThatWeirdGameDev if you are using windows then go to your command prompt, and type pip install Pillow, this may help: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/